# Git - how to find branches that may contain commits which were reverted?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-flow

We recently switched to `Git` from `SVN` (using gitflow), and I'm in the process of putting together some checks to make sure that any reverts done on a public branch are also reverted in branches cut from said public branch that may have picked up the commits to be reverted.

Simple example below. `f1` is cut from develop at commit X. Commits A, B, and C are made on f1, and f1 is merged back to develop in commit Y. f2 is cut from develop at commit Z. Commits D and E are made on f2. All changes from f1 are not reverted on develop by reverting the f1 merge commit with 'git revert -m1 '. Now, if f2 is merged to develop, it will still contain the changes from f1, and add them back to develop.

```
                               |reverts f1 
 develop-> X---o---o---Y---Z---R---P <- merge f2 to develop picks up f1
            \         /     \     /
        f1-> A---B---C  f2-> D---E
```

I've been using 'git branch -r --contains ' to find any additional branches that contain this commit.

What I'm wondering, is how can I make this better? How can I programatically check for any other branches that might contain commits from f1? Is there any way to automatically revert commits across other branches? Basically, I need to ensure that f1 cannot make it's way back to develop via any other branches like f2 that had picked up f1 commits before they were reverted.

EDIT: To eventually merge f1 commits back to develop after a fix has been added to the branch, I will rebase to create new commits for A, B, C, plus the fix commits. So, after rebase f1 would have A', B', C', and fix commits F and G.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your example it is not necessary to branch R to f2. You do not merge over the state of the files that are in E, but you merge over the changes that were done in f2. So A, B and C will still be left out in P without R being cherry-picked to f2.

To prove this statement, here a command-chain that exactly reproducres your scenario that you can execute and review: `mkdir test && cd test && git init && git checkout -b develop && touch X && git add X && git commit -m X && git branch f1 && touch o1 && git add o1 && git commit -m o1 && touch o2 && git add o2 && git commit -m o2 && git checkout f1 && touch A && git add A && git commit -m A && touch B && git add B && git commit -m B && touch C && git add C && git commit -m C && git checkout - && git merge f1 -m Y && touch Z && git add Z && git commit -m Z && git checkout -b f2 && touch D && git add D && git commit -m D && touch E && git add E && git commit -m E && git checkout - && git revert HEAD~ -m 1 -n && git commit -m R && git merge f2 -m P && gitk`